# как сделать такое скругление под логотипом?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

привет!подскажите, как сделать лучше такое скругление под логотипом?

---

еще один див добавить под картинку?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/color/344/disney-logo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto -45px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/733745/pexels-photo-733745.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/color/344/disney-logo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto -45px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать!

Comment: А если под этим скруглением не однородный фон?

Answer (score 0):

Что если просто добавить поверх белого прямоугольника половину круга и поверх этого логотип.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А если под этим скруглением не однородный фон?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant Тогда будет проще заранее сфотошопить шапку так, чтобы был нижний выступ с скруглением, а уже поверх пнг логотип ставить. Иначе через маски https://habr.com/ru/post/190246/

Comment: Согласен что можно нафотошопить но в фотошопе статичная картинка а svg можно анимировать и менять фон внутри свг..и так же испрльзовать js внутри...

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой вариант, используя псевдоэлемент **::after**. В зависимости от размера логотипа можно в стилях поиграть значениями *width*, *height* и *bottom* для **.logo::after** для достижения нужного эффекта.

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
header .logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
header .logo::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -30%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
main {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NKCPvCs/2e5cc6981b882c2830d8802455e39f0d.png">
  </div>
</header>
<main>
</main>
```

Comment: А если под этим скруглением не однородный фон?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant А какая разница? https://codepen.io/Ziegel/pen/poKJXbB

Comment: разница очевидна: 1) https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BaVoRVZ  2) https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/eYKpWeP

Comment: теперь попробуйте с таким минимализмом кода повторить тоже самое кроссбраузерно  на css

Comment: @MonkeyMutant Ваши сообщения выглядят, как будто Вы меня меня хотите чему-то научить - за это, конечно, спасибо, но кажется, что это немного оффтоп. Я предложил своё решение, оно может быть не самое лучшее и я бы больше понял поправки и уточнения к нему, чем решение совершенно другим способом. При этом, на мой взгляд, размеры "скругления" как-то визуально попроще корректировать в css, чем править координаты в svg.

Comment: @MonkeyMutant Также мой вариант предполагает создание "закругления" для логотипа один раз и следующее его переиспользование на любых страницах. Ваш же вариант, насколько я понял, предполагает изменение каждой страницы, на которой будет использоваться логотип.

Comment: Там всего одну точку менять надо а этот svg можно вставить милион раз куда угодно..ладно, я вас поняо...я не учу...мне это не надо

Comment: И вот, кстати, скругление с логотипом ... https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyKYjbM

Comment: вот кучу раз вставил: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvXKxPx

Comment: дебаты окончены... от способностей зависит